# send image and different data (integer,string) to server via REST API

Tags: android, rest

I am making an application and using Rest API to get and send data to server .now i want to send different type of data as image and string and integer and using POST method .

Answer (score -1):

Sending a Simple Request using Volley post and get :-

[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Or you can see the Example here:-

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            returnValue = response;
                            try {
                                parseFromUrl(response);
                                System.out.println(returnValue);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                             Toast.makeText(app,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Password", password);
                    params.put("RememberMe", "false");
                    params.put("ReturnUrl", url_post);
                    params.put("UserName",username);
                    params.put(name,_RequestVerificationToken);
                    return params;
                }

            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(app);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: This doesn't send integers or an image as the question asked for